# how can i do download of PDF archive of jasper report using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I have a jasper report that I need to be printed using AJAX, however, with the jquery ajax call it does not work:

```
    $.ajax(
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'ExportReport',
                    async : false,
                    data: { 
                          typeOfClient          : _type,
                          mouthOfSelect         : _mounth
                },
                    success : function (html) {
                        alert("Sucess");
                }
```

If i use submit form, this work:

```
//create dynamic form
var formularioElement = document.createElement('form');
formularioElement.setAttribute('id', 'formSync');
formularioElement.method = 'POST';
formularioElement.action = 'ExportReport';

// Create input
var formularioInput = document.createElement('input');
formularioInput.type = 'text';
formularioInput.name = 'typeOfClient';
formularioInput.value = _type;

// Create input 2
var formularioInput2 = document.createElement('input');
formularioInput2.type = 'text';
formularioInput2.name = 'mouthOfSelect';
formularioInput2.value = _mouth;

formularioElement.appendChild(formularioInput);
formularioElement.appendChild(formularioInput2);

// add the form to DOM
document.body.appendChild(formularioElement);

// submit
formularioElement.submit();
```

the both codes call the server side and create the jasper PDF equals, but just the `form.submit()` do the download of file, `the ajax code` don't download the file.

Is possible I do it with AJAX?

Comment: This question, technically, is no different than downloading a PDF using AJAX. JasperReports is not really relevant to the question, unless your code is having issues generating the report using JasperReports.

Comment: yes, you are rigth, i just need make download of a pdf file with AJAX, you know if this is possible?

Comment: Consider using a Servlet instead of AJAX. The HTML needn't be more complex than `<a href="/app/Report?p1=v1&p2=v2">Download</a>`. Works across all browsers and doesn't require AJAX. If you want to hide the parameters, make it an HTML form with a submit button that issues an HTTP POST request to the Servlet, instead of a GET request.

Comment: @DaveJarvis, thank you for you comment, I've already managed to do this with form and it works, but I need to change all 'submit ()' system calls to ajax (do not ask me why, I just got this command from my boss) I've already managed to change all but this Report, with AJAX the output file is not downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do it with AJAX because JS cannot save archives directly to a computer (for security reasons).